# Delete a cell based on content of corresponding column

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

Two requests. I tried to research online on how to delete a cell based on an index, but found nothing. I would appreciate if someone can direct me to resources about this topic (this being the solution to the problem below).

My problem is deleting the Date cell based on the corresponding trimmed.average column. If TRIMMED.AVERAGE column is empty "" or is "TRIMMED AVERAGE", the date to the right should be deleted.

I found answers that remove the entire row, but I want to keep the Variable in that row.

```
structure(list(Variable = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"), X1ST = c("", "3.44", 
"0.53", "1.66", "0.10", "0.91", "-0.25", "0.16", "-0.11", "0.16", 
"0.09", "-0.19", "0.00", "0.09", "0.09", "", "81.00", "52.75", 
"3.66", "0.58", "1ST", "0.42", "0.05", "0.29", "0.91", "-2.12", 
"", "23.14", "32.78"), X5TH = c("", "4.48", "0.81", "2.85", "0.24", 
"1.63", "0.00", "0.71", "-0.02", "0.74", "0.49", "0.51", "0.00", 
"0.48", "0.49", "", "88.58", "63.76", "4.87", "0.89", "5TH", 
"0.81", "0.17", "0.43", "1.63", "0.88", "", "37.70", "38.55"), 
X10TH = c("", "4.73", "0.99", "3.10", "0.34", "1.93", "0.00", 
"0.98", "0.00", "1.00", "0.67", "0.70", "0.00", "0.66", "0.67", 
"", "90.05", "67.76", "5.11", "1.07", "10TH", "0.98", "0.21", 
"0.51", "1.93", "1.21", "", "44.33", "40.93"), X20TH = c("", 
"4.99", "1.21", "3.38", "0.50", "2.21", "0.03", "1.25", "0.00", 
"1.28", "0.84", "0.89", "0.00", "0.82", "0.84", "", "91.53", 
"72.93", "5.36", "1.30", "20TH", "1.17", "0.27", "0.64", 
"2.21", "1.53", "", "49.94", "44.32"), X25TH = c("", "5.09", 
"1.30", "3.46", "0.56", "2.33", "0.05", "1.34", "0.00", "1.35", 
"0.91", "0.95", "0.00", "0.88", "0.91", "", "91.95", "74.57", 
"5.44", "1.39", "25TH", "1.25", "0.29", "0.67", "2.33", "1.61", 
"", "52.74", "45.64"), X50TH = c("", "5.42", "1.59", "3.84", 
"0.81", "2.81", "0.13", "1.74", "0.00", "1.75", "1.17", "1.28", 
"0.00", "1.13", "1.17", "", "93.79", "79.50", "5.78", "1.71", 
"50TH", "1.53", "0.40", "0.84", "2.81", "1.91", "", "59.58", 
"52.20"), X75TH = c("", "5.77", "1.86", "4.28", "1.15", "3.36", 
"0.24", "2.15", "0.00", "2.18", "1.50", "1.62", "0.00", "1.40", 
"1.50", "", "95.44", "83.61", "6.17", "1.98", "75TH", "1.87", 
"0.50", "1.05", "3.36", "2.28", "", "66.90", "62.47"), X80TH = c("", 
"5.91", "1.93", "4.41", "1.24", "3.51", "0.27", "2.31", "0.00", 
"2.32", "1.62", "1.73", "0.00", "1.48", "1.62", "", "95.79", 
"84.68", "6.33", "2.06", "80TH", "1.97", "0.53", "1.11", 
"3.51", "2.40", "", "69.24", "64.82"), X90TH = c("", "6.22", 
"2.12", "4.74", "1.64", "3.98", "0.37", "2.66", "0.03", "2.71", 
"2.00", "2.11", "0.00", "1.73", "2.00", "", "96.77", "86.91", 
"6.69", "2.24", "90TH", "2.21", "0.63", "1.35", "3.98", "2.69", 
"", "74.61", "76.34"), X95TH = c("", "6.68", "2.25", "5.06", 
"2.30", "4.66", "0.49", "3.16", "0.08", "3.20", "2.36", "2.45", 
"0.00", "2.01", "2.36", "", "97.61", "88.15", "7.09", "2.38", 
"95TH", "2.62", "0.72", "1.59", "4.66", "2.93", "", "79.82", 
"88.33"), X99TH = c("", "8.57", "2.59", "6.76", "13.08", 
"12.74", "1.68", "5.81", "0.28", "6.74", "4.65", "5.14", 
"0.00", "4.13", "4.65", "", "99.18", "91.06", "9.23", "2.72", 
"99TH", "4.35", "1.03", "5.48", "12.74", "3.68", "", "93.81", 
"149.14"), TRIMMED.AVERAGE = c("", "5.45", "1.58", "3.88", 
"0.88", "2.86", "0.15", "1.77", "0.00", "1.79", "1.22", "1.31", 
"0.00", "1.15", "1.22", "", "93.64", "78.75", "5.83", "1.69", 
"TRIMMED AVERAGE", "1.57", "0.40", "0.87", "2.86", "1.93", 
"", "59.66", "54.70"), Date = c("2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", "2005-03-31", 
"2005-03-31", "2005-03-31")), .Names = c("Variable", "X1ST", 
"X5TH", "X10TH", "X20TH", "X25TH", "X50TH", "X75TH", "X80TH", 
"X90TH", "X95TH", "X99TH", "TRIMMED.AVERAGE", "Date"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deleted"? You want assign `NA` to it? There is not option to delete a cell in R.

Comment: No, just empty the cell "".

Comment: You can't "empty a cell". You have to assign something there, like an empty character for example (like in akruns answer). But even `""` is "something", for example, try `class('')` or `is.vector('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%in%` to get the index of elements that are either `''` or `TRIMMED AVERAGE` in the column 'TRIMMED.AVERAGE' and use this to assign the 'Date' column values to `''`.

```
df1$Date[df1$TRIMMED.AVERAGE%in% c('', 'TRIMMED AVERAGE')] <- ''
```

Or this can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[TRIMMED.AVERAGE %chin% c('', 'TRIMMED AVERAGE'), Date:='']
```